# jquery to change progress bar with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, progress-bar

I have looked all over and found many similar threads, but none of them really answered my helped me with this specific situation.

I have a row of checkboxes, and an absolutely positioned div behind them. I want to be able to check a checkbox and have the width of the background change to make it appear like a progress bar.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/f280wpa3bovlipq/unchecked.png
https://www.dropbox.com/s/r8gt9jmvhi6d4t0/checked.png

I'm extremely new to jQuery. I know how to change css with jQuery, something like

```
$('.workflow-progress').css('background-size', "33% 39px");
```

but I'm having trouble piecing together how to make the css change based on the checkbox status. Also, if the third box is checked before the first two, I'd like the first two to check themselves automatically, but that's probably a problem for another day.

Comment: Please provide a jsfidle of what you've written until now.

Comment: PLease provide us with at least your html setup and any jquery code you might have already

Comment: Or you can take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/drewP/Jc6Jj/ and just customize it to fit your code.

Comment: @Drew Beautiful, that's just about what I was looking for! http://jsfiddle.net/darrensq/kLDcN/1/